# Spring doesn't correctly serialize JSON to Java Map

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a form that contains multiple radio inputs and one textarea input that I send using axios from a ReactJs client. The request looks like this:

```
  axios.post("/wellbeing/" + params.wellbeingSurveyType, { formAnswersJson: formAnswers })
    .then(res => {
      // logic
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // logic
    })
```

The 'formAnswers' object looks like this:
[image]

I then receive the request from a Spring controller that looks like the following:

```
    @PostMapping("{wellbeingSurveyType}")
    public WellbeingSurveySubmission submitSurvey(
            @PathVariable WellbeingSurveyType wellbeingSurveyType,
            @RequestBody String formAnswersJson) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(formAnswersJson, HashMap.class);
        return new WellbeingSurveySubmission(); //ignore this
    }
```

When I call the 'toString()' method on the result object it seems to correctly print out the map values:
[image]

But when I try to actually operate on the object (which is parsed as a LinkedHashMap) I cannot access the keys or values:
[image]

When I try to open up the object using the debugging tool it seems to store a reference to itself as a value:
[image]

The result I want is simply a Map<String, String> that represents the JSON but I am unsure why this behavior is happening.

Any help or tips on how to do this in a better way would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think your map has only one key (size = 1) which is probably "formAnswersJson" as you defined in your request: `{ formAnswersJson: formAnswers }`. So the mapper seems to work correctly. Try to call `result.get("formAnswersJson");` to see if you will get your Map of objects. However, since you seem to work with Spring mvc, it's always a good idea to define your own form object (which can hold a map of course) and use this as a param of your controller method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I agree that I should probably define my own form object instead of taking just a json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright the best way I found to make this work was to deconstruct the JSON object in the axios post request like so:

```
axios.post("/wellbeing/" + params.wellbeingSurveyType, { ...formAnswers })
        .then(res => {
          // logic
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // logic
        })
```

Works better as if I just pass the formAnswers object it unnecessarily wraps the object i.e. A hashmap that contains a single key-value pair 'formAnswers'.

Although as The Frozen One mentioned, it would be better to define a dedicated form object and take it as a param in the spring controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a JavaScript object as the 2nd parameter to the `axios.post()` function, Axios will automatically serialize the object to JSON for you.

So, with this line of code :

```
axios.post("/wellbeing/" + params.wellbeingSurveyType, { formAnswersJson: formAnswers })
```

You are basically sending object with key `fromAnswersJson` and value `fromAnswers` to your rest controller and Spring will deserilize it like  a `Map` with key `fromAnswersJson` and value `fromAnswers`

To get what you want just send your request like this :

```
axios.post("/wellbeing/" + params.wellbeingSurveyType, formAnswers )
```

Answer (score 0):

It Seems like the conversion from String to Map in java does not go smoothly from what I see in your printscreen.

Personally, I do not work like that when I handle requests. I create a dto object and give that in the controller as input. The fact that you have variables that the name is a number make that a bit more complicated since java cannot accept that as a valid variable name, but probably (did not test it) can be overcome by using @JsonProperty. So my solution would be the following

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyRequestDto {
    @JsonProperty("user-comment")
    private String userComment;
    @JsonProperty("0")
    private String zero;
    @JsonProperty("1")
    private String one;
    @JsonProperty("2")
    private String two;
...

}
```

I added lombok getters and setters ofcourse you can add your own if you don't use lombok.

Then replace the input in your controller

```
@PostMapping("{wellbeingSurveyType}")
public WellbeingSurveySubmission submitSurvey(
        @PathVariable WellbeingSurveyType wellbeingSurveyType,
        @RequestBody MyRequestDto request) throws JsonProcessingException {
        request.getUserComment()
        return new WellbeingSurveySubmission(); //ignore this
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ideally yes I would have a DTO object but the number of questions can vary (since there are a lot of different types of surveys with similar structure but different number of questions) so I cannot have a static DTO with fixed number of questions. Perhaps storing them as a map within the DTO would be a more suitable approach.

Comment: Then your body is kind of weird, I would expect you to have a list that contains objects of the a new type and then the size is irrelevant.

Comment: I would expect your body to be like this

`{"user-comment":"thisisacomment","questions":[{"question":"question","answer":"answer"},{"question":"anotherquestion","answer":"anotheranswer"}]}`